# How to pass a Type into ConverterParameter in UWP?

Tags: uwp-xaml

Since you can't use x:type in UWP, how would you pass the type of an object as the converter parameter into a converter? Basically, I want to do this in UWP:

```
Header="{x:Bind NavMenu.SelectedItem, 
                Mode=OneWay, 
                Converter={StaticResource ObjectToStringConverter}, 
                ConverterParameter={x:type NavigationViewItem}}"
```

Yes, I realize since I'm using x:Bind I can just cast the object directly. However, Resharper complains about the cast and marks it as a syntax error, so I want to work around it by using a converter. Also, just because I'm curious how you go about passing a Type into a converter in XAML for another usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to pass a Type into ConverterParameter in UWP?

You can’t bind a value directly on the `ConverterParameter`, The reason why is that the `ConverterParameter` IS NOT a depency property but a *simple* object. In this situation you can’t use Bindings and pass `x:type` is wrong syntax.

For your requirement, you could create a dependency property on the converter and not using the `ConverterParameter` : To be able to create a DP, your converter must inherits from `DependencyObject`. For detail steps you could refer this blog  [**WinRT Converter Parameter Binding**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mim/2013/03/11/tips-winrt-converter-parameter-binding/)

**Update**

if you want to pass Type parameter, you could use get type [Functions in x:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings).

For example:

```
static public class MyHelpers
{
    public static Type GetType(object ele)
    {
        return ele.GetType();
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind local:MyHelpers.GetType(Item)}" />
```

Comment: To clarify, I'm not trying to bind a value to the converter parameter. I just want to know how to pass a type into it in xaml.

Comment: I was asking how you pass a Type into the **ConverterParameter** not bind to it like you showed. I needed to use the binding value AND the converter parameter for what I was doing. However, you did lead me to the idea of just using function binding instead of the Converter. You did help me figure out the issue so I'll mark it as accepted. 

I wonder if a custom Markup Extension would have worked for the old way I was trying to do it. Might try it out just for the knowledge.